# How to change column values and sort with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

print(df)

     cat      A         B           C
0     cat1    0.787575  0.159330    0.053095
1     cat10   0.770698  0.169487    0.059815
2     cat11   0.792689  0.152043    0.055268
3     cat12   0.785066  0.160361    0.054573
4     cat13   0.795455  0.150464    0.054081
5     cat14   0.794873  0.150700    0.054426
..    ....
8     cat19   0.811585  0.140207    0.048208
9     cat2    0.797202  0.152033    0.050765
10    cat20   0.801607  0.145137    0.053256
11    cat21   0.792689  0.152043    0.055268
    ....
```

Obviously, `cat1` is in the incorrect order, because `cat2` should go after `cat1`, not after `cat19`.

What methods can one use to rectify this?

My idea would be to relabel each single-digit `cat` and then sort with `.sort()`. However, my method for doing this doesn't work.

```
df = df.rename(index={'cat1': 'cat01'})
df = df.rename(index={'cat2': 'cat02'})
df = df.rename(index={'cat3': 'cat03'})
...
df = df.rename(index={'cat9': 'cat09'})
```

It appears one has to change the index to the `cat` column, then use the above method, and sort.

However, I am still typing out far too much. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex expression to extract the the digits (`\d+` means one or more digits), use [`zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) to zero pad them, and then add `cat` back to the result. I've used `3` for `zfill`, so `1` becomes `001`.  You can adjust this to your needs.

I've also created a mask to only apply this to rows that have digits.

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('ABC'))
df['cat'] = ['catZ', 'cat10', 'cat11', 'cat12', 'cat13']

digit_str = df.cat.str.extract(r'(\d+)').str.zfill(3)
mask = digit_str.notnull()
df.loc[mask, 'cat'] = 'cat' + digit_str[mask]

>>> df
          A         B         C     cat
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738    catZ
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278  cat010
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219  cat011
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274  cat012
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  cat013
```

Comment: There is one cat named `catZ`. Unfortunately, with the above method, this translates into a `NaN`

Comment: With the new edits, you will erase `catZ` into `cat0`.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang It works in the sample above, why do you think it will result in `cat0` for `catZ`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
print df.cat.str.len() == 4
0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
8     False
9      True
10    False
11    False
Name: cat, dtype: bool

print df.cat.str[-1]
0     1
1     0
2     1
3     2
4     3
5     4
8     9
9     2
10    0
11    1
Name: cat, dtype: object
```

```
df.loc[(df.cat.str.len() == 4) & 
       (df.cat != 'catZ'), 'cat'] =  'cat' + df.cat.str[-1].str.zfill(2)
print df
      cat         A         B         C
0   cat01  0.787575  0.159330  0.053095
1   cat10  0.770698  0.169487  0.059815
2   cat11  0.792689  0.152043  0.055268
3   cat12  0.785066  0.160361  0.054573
4   cat13  0.795455  0.150464  0.054081
5   cat14  0.794873  0.150700  0.054426
8   cat19  0.811585  0.140207  0.048208
9   cat02  0.797202  0.152033  0.050765
10  cat20  0.801607  0.145137  0.053256
11   catZ  0.792689  0.152043  0.055268
```

Comment: There is one cat named `catZ`. Unfortunately, with the above method, this translates into a `cat0Z`. I suppose one would first check whether `cat` is followed by a digit?

Comment: I first check `length` of string and if is `4` and not `catZ` apply `str.zfill`